# Create x number of spring batch jobs pragmatically or through xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am trying to create a set of spring batch jobs based on number files available to read. These jobs will run asynchronously using a split flow. I have the xml configuration with 10 different flows hard coded as mentioned below. I have to make it dynamic, could you please guide me on how to convert this to java based configuration

```
<batch:job id="job">
    <batch:split id="" task-executor="">
        <batch:flow>
             <batch:step id="step1">
                 <batch:tasklet>
                    <batch:chunk reader="reader1" writer="writer1" commit-interval="500" />
                 </batch:tasklet>
             </batch:step>
        </batch:flow>
        <batch:flow>
             <batch:step id="step2">
                 <batch:tasklet>
                    <batch:chunk reader="reader2" writer="writer2" commit-interval="500" />
                 </batch:tasklet>
             </batch:step>
        </batch:flow>
        <batch:flow>
             <batch:step id="step-n">
                 <batch:tasklet>
                    <batch:chunk reader="reader-n" writer="writer-n" commit-interval="500" />
                 </batch:tasklet>
             </batch:step>
        </batch:flow>

    </batch:split>
</batch:job>
```

Comment: Are you referring to concurrent execution of the batch jobs ? Or chunking the file reads

Answer (score 0):

Use the all the different Builder-classes of spring batch to create your job dynamically with javacode. You can't do this with an XML-based approach. 
Use the appropriate annotations to configure the spring context with java classes.